# advice needed for displaying XML in HTML automatically

Tags: php, html, xml

ok, now i have 3 files, which is update_XML.php, showXML.html and data.xml.

i use the update_XML.php to update the data in data.xml, then i use showXML.html to display the data.

my question is how should i call the update_xml.php to update the data.xml automtically?

i only manage to do it manually.

what already in my mind is only use timeout() in html to refresh the showXML.html

but how about the updating part ? use timeout() function too?

i need  some advice about this, especially a correct flow.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on if your website is accessible to just you or not, if it's not update_XML.php will be called for every user when using `setTimeout();`, also JS can be disabled.

Your option is setting up a cron job on your server.

cron jobs are basicly automated tasks on a scheduled base depending on how often you want this cron job to be executed.

[Here is some documentation on cronjobs](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

**NOTE** this is a tutorial for *nix systems.